# How to group JSON data into week object based on DATE in Node JS/Javascript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, json, sql-server

I have last 30 days data getting from MS SQL server Database and i want to group JSON object based on week numbers using node JS . I have JSON object in below format

```
       var data = [{name:"abc",status:"Pending",created_timestamp:"2020-01-12 12:00:12"},
            {name:"abc1",status:"Pending",created_timestamp:"2020-12-12 12:00:12"},
            {name:"abc2",status:"Pending",created_timestamp:"2020-17-12 12:00:12"},
            {name:"abc3",status:"Rejected",created_timestamp:"2020-20-12 12:00:12"},
            {name:"abc4",status:"Rejected",created_timestamp:"2020-22-12 12:00:12"}]
```

i want to get output in below format:

```
    var graphDetails = [{Week:1,
                         Pending:1,
                         Rejected:0},
                         {Week:2,
                         Pending:2,
                         Rejected:0}, 
                         {Week:3,
                         Pending:1,
                         Rejected:1}...]
```

Comment: You've tagged javascript and SQL Server here; what language are you after the solution in, and what does the question have to do with the other language?

Comment: why not get week and year from the data base?

Answer (score 0):

```
var data = [
  { name: "abc", status: "Pending", created_timestamp: "2020-01-12 12:00:12" },
  { name: "abc1", status: "Pending", created_timestamp: "2020-12-12 12:00:12" },
  { name: "abc2", status: "Pending", created_timestamp: "2020-17-12 12:00:12" },
  {
    name: "abc3",
    status: "Rejected",
    created_timestamp: "2020-20-12 12:00:12",
  },
  {
    name: "abc4",
    status: "Rejected",
    created_timestamp: "2020-22-12 12:00:12",
  },
];

function getWeekNumber(d) {
  // Copy date so don't modify original
  d = new Date(Date.UTC(d.getFullYear(), d.getMonth(), d.getDate()));
  // Set to nearest Thursday: current date + 4 - current day number
  // Make Sunday's day number 7
  d.setUTCDate(d.getUTCDate() + 4 - (d.getUTCDay() || 7));
  // Get first day of year
  var yearStart = new Date(Date.UTC(d.getUTCFullYear(), 0, 1));
  // Calculate full weeks to nearest Thursday
  var weekNo = Math.ceil(((d - yearStart) / 86400000 + 1) / 7);
  // Return array of year and week number
  return [d.getUTCFullYear(), weekNo];
}

var updated = {};
data.forEach((element) => {
  let week = getWeekNumber(new Date(element.created_timestamp));
  let weekDetail = updated[week];
  switch (element.status) {
    case "pending":
      weekDetail.pending = weekDetail.pending + 1;
      break;
    default:
      weekDetail.rejected = weekDetail.rejected + 1;
      break;
  }
  updated[week] = {
    week: week,
    pending: weekDetail.pending,
    rejected: weekDetail.rejected,
  };
});
```

Hope this will help you out from your problem